# Select all images using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and C#. I am trying to retrieve all images from folder and show it on page, but it's only selecting one image.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="col-lg-5">            
    <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" />
</form>
```

My C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Blog
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blogconnection"].ToString());
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string allimage;
            string qry="select * from images";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            SqlDataReader dr =cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["Image_Path"])))
                   {                                             
                        Image.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(dr["Image_Path"]);                                         
                   }
                }
           }
           con.Close();
       }               
    }
}
```

**What I want:**   I want to select all image which path is store in sql table.

**Additional:** is there a way to select videos from folder which path is store in sql, mean to select videos and images from different folder and show both on same page by date specified or by latest upload etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit #1**

In php i use the below code to get all images and show it, is there any thing equivalent to the below code in ASP.NET?

*PHP Code*

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$smt=$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM post');
$smt->execute();

?>
<?php include 'header.php';

?>
<div class="">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
include 'nav.php';
}
else
{
include 'nav-simple.php';
}
?>
<?php include 'slider.php';?>

<?php include 'right_sidebar.php';?>

    <div class="col-md-1 top_space"></div>
<div class="container col-md-8 main-container-top">


    <br/>

<div class="">
    <?php while ($gdata = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): ?>
        <a href="#" class="col-md-4"><img src="posts/<?php echo $gdata->Post_Path; ?>" alt="image" class="post-image"/></a>
        <div class="media-body col-md-8 post pull-left">
            <div class="post-overview">
                <ul>
                    <li class="post-category"><?php echo $gdata->Category; ?></li>
                    <li class="post-timestemp">Post on <?php echo $gdata->Post_Date; ?></li>
                </ul>


                <a href="post-description.php?id=<?php echo $gdata->Id ?>"><h4
                        class="media-heading h4"><?php echo $gdata->Title; ?></h4></a>

                <p class="post-text"><?php echo $gdata->Post; ?></p><br/>
            </div>


        </div>
<div class="post-image-space"></div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: u cannot squeeze multiples images into one asp:image object.  how about gridview?

Comment: Put a Repeater control on your page, with an Image control inside its ItemTemplate.  Bind the Repeater control to a list of image URLs.  Set the Image's ImageUrl property to a suitable data-binding expression.

Comment: in PHP html generates with the code loop, in ASP.NET you have specified a single Image type object and trying to give all the images to one HTML object which will shoe you last image retrieved always.

Answer (score 8):

In the code behind write your `Collection()` method to retrieve images as a `List` of `Strings` like this (*Also it is better to use [`Using`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using) statements*):

```
protected IEnumerable<string> Collection()
{
     string address = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blogconnection"].ToString();
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(address))
     {
         con.Open();
         string qry = "select * from images";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
         using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             if (!dr.HasRows) return allimage;
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["Image_Path"])))
                 {
                     yield return (dr["Image_Path"].ToString());
                 }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Then either you can use `asp:Repeater` like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="imgCats">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div>
            <img src='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' alt="" />
         </div>                  
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="imgCats" runat="server" SelectMethod="Collection" 
          TypeName="WebApplication1.WebForm8">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="col-lg-5">
  <div>
    <ul>
        <% var drc = Collection();
           foreach (var item in drc)
           { %>
            <li>
                <img src="<%: item %>"/>
            </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically add new asp:image objects to the form1.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = dr["Image_Path"].ToString();
img.AlternateText = "Test image";
form1.Controls.Add(img);
```

Comment: what about the while loop? is while not working on such process in asp.net, because in php i get such result using while loop. is there a way to use while loop?

Comment: Dynamically adding images is possible, but you need to do it at the right point in the page life cycle for them to play well with postbacks. It would be far better to use a Repeater and then bind the data to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this statement:

```
Image.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(dr["Image_Path"]);
```

What does this statement do? It assigns **each** `image path` value to **only one** `Image.ImageUrl`. So, the `Image.ImageUrl` will hold the last assigned `image path`. The result is only one picture will be displayed. This is **not** what you want.

What you want is: show all pictures --> assign **each** `image path` to **each** `Image.ImageUrl` --> **dynamically create the `Image` and add it to the form**. So, instead of writing that statement, you should do something like:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = dr["Image_Path"].ToString();
img.AlternateText = "Test image";
form1.Controls.Add(img);
```

The code is **not tested**. Just focus on the idea. You can do it like this, or use the `repeater`, or your own way, it's up to you.

Feel free to ask me if you find something unclear :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use  control to display images as you want with custom styling also

Answer (score 1):

1) Its obvious you can not display multiple images into a single HTML object.
You must have to use `Repeater`, `GridView` or `DataGrid` or dynamic HTML generation based on how you want to show it on your page(i.e. HTML design)

2) Follow ASP.NET page life-cycle events properly(in your case you can write code in `PageLoad()` event once you finished initializing `Repeater`, `Gridview` or `Datagrid`)

3)You can also show videos but for that you need some player, it won't be that much simple(you can use Third party tools)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to make it work. Instead defining image in aspx add it dynamically from your code behind.

Your Modified ASP.NET code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="col-lg-5">            

</form>
```

Your Modified C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Blog
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blogconnection"].ToString());
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string allimage;
            string qry="select * from images";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            SqlDataReader dr =cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["Image_Path"])))
                   {                                             
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = dr["Image_Path"].ToString();
                        img.AlternateText = dr["Image_Path"].ToString();
                        form1.Controls.Add(img);                                         
                   }
                }
           }
           con.Close();
       }               
    }
}
```

Comment: well your code will not make clear UI,I mean your code is not UI compatible.

Answer (score -3):

I have added some screen shots here hope you can continue from here on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: People don't code with pictures. Code is text. Use text in your answer, not pictures. Pictures should only be supplementary. Also, this doesn't answer the question of getting multiple pictures onto the page.

Comment: It is a screen shot from visual studio. Like I said I am not sure how you want to render it. You had one image  but this give you all the images. Let me know how you want to display the images, do you have to render in e.g. div element or ASP.NET form control, e.g. GridView? Let me know