# How to display database values in div

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to get values from database and display it in a `div`.
here I am getting values from mysql database and I have HTML in `.aspx` page. I have 20 records and I want to print the data in different `divs`.
how can I do it using `for` loop.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Animal Name here</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Animal image</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          string scon = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=animal_adoption_site;UID=root;";
          MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(scon);
          String s = "select animal_pet_name,animal_donation_plan,animal_image_uploaded from animal_details";
          MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
     }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          string s = ex.ToString();
          Response.Write(s);
     }
}
```

Comment: You can place a `Repeater` control on your page, with an `ItemTemplate`. Then **Bind** the `Repeater` control to a list of `animal_details`. check this answer may be usefull:http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694399/2946329

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

Imagine in the server you have the following

```
public List<string> MyItems { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyItems = new List<string>();
        MyItems.Add("Item 1");
        MyItems.Add("Item 2");
        MyItems.Add("Item 3");
        MyItems.Add("Item 4");
    }
```

In the client you can do a for loop for the items

```
<% foreach (string myItem in MyItems)
{ %>

   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading"><%: myItem %></div>
        <div class="panel-body">Animal image</div>     
      </div>
   </div>

<%} %>
```