# Trying to show the image in website after Choosing it and then saving same in db

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show an image on website after choosing it and then saving it to database.
C# .aspx

```
<td ><strong>Product Photograph</strong></td>
         <td ><asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1"/>
             <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload" />             
             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
         </td>
```

c#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/Images/" + fileName));
            }}
}
```

How to attach choosen image with ID="Image1" i don't know.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33694399/2946329

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to read image from file and bind in asp:Image control

```
 Image1.ImageUrl= "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\IMG_20171003_164329.jpg'.

Comment: Check fileName at first.It's may your fileName has invalid path.because I tested here and it was ok.Thanks

Comment: Hi my file location is at "E:\pc\Projects\TDC\TDC_Project\Images\loader.gif" but error is "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\loader.gif'." how to resolve it